# I have this code written in JavaScript what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

how can I make my code to work with both options? because now it only use one selection because I believe the code is not proper duplicated

```
<form action="https://track.aftership.com/tuffnells/" method="get" target="_blank" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="reference-number" id="reference-number" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var form       = document.querySelector('#my-form'),
      text_field = document.querySelector('#reference-number');

  function submitHandler(){
    // build the new url and open a new window
    var url = form.action + text_field.value + '?tracking_account_number=318843';
    window.open(url);

// prevent form from being submitted because we already
// called the request in a new window
return false;
  }

  // attach custom submit handler
  form.onsubmit = submitHandler;
</script>

<form action="https://track.aftership.com/tnt-reference/" method="get"             target="_blank" id="my-form1">
  <input type="text" name="reference-number1" id="reference-number1" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var form       = document.querySelector('#my-form1'),
      text_field = document.querySelector('#reference-number1');

  function submitHandler(){
    // build the new url and open a new window
    var url = form.action + text_field.value + '?';
    window.open(url);

    // prevent form from being submitted because we already
    // called the request in a new window
    return false;
  }

  // attach custom submit handler
  form.onsubmit = submitHandler;
</script>
```

how can i make this work twice, because now is working only once.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. *Huge* difference.

Comment: Please tell us which of these forms isn't working correctly, and how it does behave when you submit it. Also check your javascript console for errors. To me it looks like correct (although poor quality) code.

Answer (score 0):

just rename your variables in the second script part, this:

`var form       = document.querySelector('#my-form1'),
      text_field = document.querySelector('#reference-number1');`

to:

```
 var form1       = document.querySelector('#my-form1'),
  text_field1 = document.querySelector('#reference-number1');
```

also change the (on the second script) :

```
 var url = form.action + text_field.value + '?';
window.open(url);
```

to:

```
 var url1 = form1.action + text_field1.value + '?';
window.open(url1);
```

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cLhvuy68/